# How can I create a temporary table using PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crud, temp-tables, petapoco

I need to check if a temporary table exist, delete it, create it and generally perform crud operations on this table using PetaPoco and C# like the following example.
How can I do it?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
END
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable (phone VARCHAR (10) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS)

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable (phone) ...
SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable
... etc ...
```

Comment: [This question's title has been discussed on Meta SE chat.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2029407#2029407)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you can (I haven't tried), the point of temp tables it's a temp space where to store thing when you are writing stored procedures.

If you are using PetaPoco it's much better to use C# memory structures (like List) to store the temp values.

Comment: you are right that's correct! I will do what you suggesting and just for exercise i'll try to figure out how to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TempCustomer
end

CREATE TABLE #TempCustomer
( 
  [CustomerID] nchar(5)
, [CompanyName] nvarchar(40)
)

INSERT INTO #TempCustomer ( [CustomerID] , [CompanyName])
Select 'A', 'AA' UNION ALL Select 'B', 'BB'

Select * from #TempCustomer

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TempCustomer
end
```

Comment: It might be helpful to readers if you'd write a thing or two explaining what you're doing to accompany the code. :)

Comment: my friend is not what i'm looking for... Thank you